# Linux system("top -p pid") command in program

Tags: linux

I have a Linux program that is interspersed with calls to the system API, specifically `system("top")`, so I can monitor virtual memory at various points in the program. I print the memory stats 4 times, as well as attempting to print other data in between these calls.

However, when my program is complete, it looks as if the `top` command is refreshing the page, so the other data I need to print is being obliterated. I tried to add a number of iterations, as in, `system("top -p pid -n 1)` but I had the same problems.

Is there a way to have a call to `top` in Linux not refresh the output buffer? I don't know where else to turn. Thanks!

Comment: No it's not. You could **scoll up** to see your output. I tested on Konsole, and all my outputs were there.

Comment: Not the case in mine, I don't know why. It's just a jumble of data from `system("top")`; in fact, I can't even see the command line where I started the program.

Comment: on Ubuntu? Do you have ``scrollback`` enabled??

Comment: It's a version of Ubuntu my professor mandates that we use. It's ugly in VirtualBox, I have to right click to access any menu at all on startup. How would I find settings for the terminal Xterm in VirtualBox?

Comment: do you have ``gnome-terminal`` in your Ubuntu? Try that instead of Xterm.  I rarely use xterm so I know little about it.

Comment: I don't unfortunately. Just Xterm. I'm as new to this as anyone can be. Oh well, I'm sure the professor will be reasonable. I hope. Thanks for your help.

Comment: But one thing to note, it's not your program's problem:)

Answer (score 1):

You can open the relevant files in /proc for yourself and present the information as you like.